# Чем лучше проводить регистрацию на сайте?

Tags: python, selenium, request, scrapy

Делал регистрацию через selenium питон и задался вопросом, если способ сделать этот процесс быстрее?
Мб другие библиотеки такие как requests или scrapy фрейм?

Comment: Чем вам больше нравится, тем и делайте

Comment: Спасибо, мог и не тратить время...